Disguise Self but illusion looks like it does different things
I have this one illusion spell at the back of my mind but can't remember the name. What it's supposed to do is create illusion of you, exactly where you're standing (kind of like Disguise Self) but the illusion does different things than you actually do. It might conceal spellcasting or make it look like a different spell is being cast, that's the main use if I remember correctly.

Are you sure this spell was for Pathfinder? I ask because I've seen a spell like this for D&D, but not Pathfinder.

Illusion of Calm

When casting this spell, you create an illusory double that takes the same space of you. That double makes it look like you are standing still, even when you are not. While under the effects of this spell, you do not provoke attacks of opportunity when you cast a spell, make a ranged attack with a thrown weapon, or move out of your first square during a move action. It does not hide ranged attacks made with any type of projectile weapon.
When a creature hits you with an attack of any type, it gains a saving throw to disbelieve the figment. On a successful saving throw, it successfully disbelieves and the spell’s effect ends for that creature.


I am... not quite sure how it works. As a 1st level spell, it doesn't give any bonus to AC for not being quite where you seem to be. But stranger still, I'm not sure it prevents Spellcraft checks to identify spells you cast; perhaps that's implied rather than being explicit in the text. Nonetheless, it seems to be what you're looking for.

I dunno. It seems like the spell makes "it look like you are standing still, even when you are not," and if you're standing still, then it looks like you're not casting using somatic or material components (therefore making some spells impossible to discern). I'd recommend that spells cast while the subject of this effect can still be identified by their other properties after they've been cast, though, much like folks can still see the arrow fly from the subject's (illusory) standing-still figure.

@HeyICanChan The funny thing is, the spell specifies it doesn't work with projectile weapons like arrows - and does work with thrown weapons. I am not sure why.
